# Anchor tag not works in IE6 to open a PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

Anchor tag not works in IE6 to open a PDF.

my code

```
<a title="Report 2010-01-31" href="/documents/reports/2010-01-31.pdf" target="_blank" class="documentLink">Work Report</a>
```

Its work in all Browsers, except IE6.
I didn't understand why its not working in IE6.

Comment: Please define "not working."  How is it failing?

Comment: I agree with David. You need to provide us with more information. Are you getting 404 Not Found?

Comment: when I click the link its work nothing.

Comment: @DhrubaJyoti: “its work nothing” — that’s not more information, that’s what you said before. Please explain *how* it’s not working. What do you expect to happen when you click the link? What actually happens?

Comment: Dou you imply it does work with other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Is the file on /documents/reports/ ?
is it named correctly 2010-01-31.pdf ?

does it work if you replace the url directly instead of clicking the link? (if this doesn't work then the error is in finding the file).

@DhrubaJyoti we need to know what is happening. I Mean more details.

When you click is anything happening? 
is another window opened?

Does the browser say anything like file not found?

PS: The / implies going back to the root of the site.
So if you are on http://www.mysite.com/thisweb/thisfolder/thispage.html
and you got a link that points to /anotherfolder/apdf.pdf
it will be http://www.mysite.com/anotherfolder/apdf.pdf
you might be expecting it to be under /thisweb but this might be concealing you.

Answer (score 0):

If you download you PDF-file to the PC with the (outdated) IE6 and open it with Acrobat, does this work?

I had some problems with the Acrobat. If it never started on the maschine, it shows an licence-agreement.  The acrobat did not show the PDF from within IE, if the Acrobat's reader Licence is not accppted. And as browserplugin it doesn't show the licence agreement-window.